# Rails Adjacency List - Parent Child Tree - Get root

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this app I have a parent-child tree.  The model (with some data) looks like this:

```
Subjects
Subject_id Subject_name Parent_id
1          Plants       0
2          Animals      0
3          Bacteria     0
4          Tree         1
5          Grass        1
6          Dog          2
7          Pine         4
```

The relationship looks like this:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Subject"
  has_many :children, class_name: "Subject", foreign_key: "parent_id"
end
```

I want to get the parents with parent_id 0.  How do I do that?

I know one solution is to create a root parent, and call that with .children to get the root parents children, but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: I tried it in the console and I got NameError: uninitialized constant Parent

Comment: sorry `Subject.where( :parent_id => 0 )`. I've overseen the class_name.

Comment: That would get me the Subject with Subject_id = 0.  I'm trying to get the Subjects with Parent_id = 0

Comment: That's it thanks.  I'll read more about there .where section.  If you want to put your comment as an answer I'll select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

former comment

```
Subject.where( :parent_id => 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

First when getting Active record, starts with capital letter.
Secondly, make it singular.

```
subjects.find_by
```

should be

```
Subject.find_by
```

Third, user lowercase in naming table field in Database, like.

```
Parent_id >> parent_id
```

Next, you **has_many** relationship should be in **Parent Model**

Let say like this:

**Parent model:**

```
has_many :subjects
```

**Subject Model:**

```
belongs_to :parent
```

Get parent from Subject Controller.

```
@subject = Subject.all
```

In view, you have to iterate it like:

```
<% @subject.each do |sub| %>
  <%= sub.parent.title %> //title field for ex.
<% end %>
```

But if you want to get one Subject and it's parent data, you can do like:

```
@subject = Subject.first
@subject.parent.title //example field from Parent Table
```

Comment: Hi Aldrien, I'm a bit confused when you say "Next, you has_many relationship should be in Parent Model".  My model is self referencing.  That's how it builds the tree structure.